# Robot Framework - New Tab Issue

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, ride

I'm doing my first project on robot framework using ride.

I managed to open a browser and make the login as well, however, after the login, the page opens another tab and all the command I inserted on ride seems to not work on the new tab.

I have tried to use (commands within the blue rectangle)
[image]

However, I got the log `ValueError: Invalid time string 'GWMS 2.0'.`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: you have to select the tab you will use

Answer (score 1):

you have to select windows to use a new tab.

```
Select Window    title="title windows"
```

Comment: I have tried al well, but it didnt work, I have updated the question with a print from the ride, do you know where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: why not use select window @RafaelRodriguesSantos